# Iterating nested structs in golang on a template

Tags: templates, go, range

I have the following code and would like to iterate though the themes in a template, but for the life of me I can't seem to get past the fact it is a nested container.

```
type ThemeList struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Themes"`
    Themes []Theme `xml:"Theme"`
}

type Theme struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Theme"`
    Name string `xml:"Name,attr"`
    Page string `xml:"Page,attr"`
    Tag string `xml:"Tag,attr"`
    Day string `xml:"Day,attr"`
}

// Fetch the current XML document and return the Themelist[]
func openXML(filename string) ThemeList {

    xmlFile, _ := os.Open(filename)
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    XMLdata, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var t ThemeList
    xml.Unmarshal(XMLdata, &t)

    return t
}
```

How would one output these in a {{range}} where each theme is part of an individual list items?  The output would use .Name .Tag and so on in the template as I look though them.

Comment: Perhaps I don't need to pass in the entire themes structure here since it is just a container of themes?  It was only needed because of the structure of the incoming xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following template:

```
<ul>{{range .Themes}}
  <li>{{.Name}} {{.Tag}}{{end}}
</ul>
```

and execute it with the data argument as a `*ThemeList`.

[Playground Example](http://play.golang.org/p/TUC2rJCoPm)

Comment: Thank you!  What I also discovered is that I can pass only the underlying []Theme collection.  I see you did the same thing by basically using the .Themes in the range indicator.

Comment: why would you use a pointer here vs just the copy variable?  I am sure you know a good reason, but I am just starting out here and want to understand better.